# What is the current consensus on passing data to in tab navigation for react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have been successful in passing data between the regular stack navigator however I am struggling to achieve the same result in the tab navigator. Currently I have this. Assume the object has data in it.

```
    const {Object} = route.params;    
    return (        
        <NavigationContainer independent={true}> 
            <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <Tab.Screen name="Shop" component={HomeShop} params={Object}/>   
                <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeMain} params={Object}/> 
                <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={HomeProfile} params={Object}/>      
            </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

When I print out the route prop of the navigation it returns undefined. I have read that one way to do it is to use an async storage. I plan to implement realm in the future however since I intend for my user to go between these screens farely often, i am worried that local storage would be too slow. The object is also a changing value as it essentially holds all the data in the session from when it is initially fetched and while it is being edited.

Answer (score 0):

do route params not work in tab navigator when navigating between screens?
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

i dont think you would need to add a params object to all your screens. if there is something you want to have globally, i think that saving it in redux is better.

Comment: Ah, I might have to go read up on how redux works. Correct me if im wrong but it seems like its basically persistent memory between screens? if thats true then I think this is probably perfect to solve a bunch of my problems

Comment: @KatSamson yeah you can save data and access it from any screen